# SDWebImage - SDWebImagePrefetcher not using transformDownloadedImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage, prefetch

I am currently successfully using 'SDWebImageManager downloadImageWithURL' for downloading single images , followed by the delegate method 'transformDownloadedImage' automatically called upon completion to resize the images before caching them.

I would like, however, in the background to prefetch a bunch of images (~25) not yet displayed using the prefetcher code below in a similar way. However the problem is that the 'transformDownloadedImage' delegate is not called upon completion (of 1 or all the images) - images are cached as is.

```
    SDWebImagePrefetcher *prefetcher = [SDWebImagePrefetcher sharedImagePrefetcher];
    [prefetcher prefetchURLs:array progress:nil completed:^(NSUInteger completedNo, NSUInteger skippedNo) {
    }];
```

Am I missing something? or is there some other efficient way to do this by pulling out the cached images upon completion, resizing, and reinserting? I am using "UIImage+Resize" to resize and manipulate, and obviously this needs to happen in background without blocking the UI.

Any and all advice about how to go about this efficiently will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `SDWebImagePrefetcher` you'll notice that it's using `SDWebImageManager` to perform the downloads, and it's available as a property. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
prefetcher.manager.delegate = self;
```

Now you can implement the `downloadImageWithURL` delegate method as you did before. I didn't try it but it should work.

Comment: Yes - Thank You!!!  That exactly did it - it works beautifully now. I saw `SDWebImagePrefetcher` was using `SDWebImageManager` , but couldn't figure out why it's delegate was not being called.

Comment: Wow ! and I tried 
[SDWebImagePrefetcher sharedImagePrefetcher].delegate = ...
and did not understand why the delegate not called. THANKS !